# rename file extension name in Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac

I never thought I'd ask a dumb question like this.

I was trying to change a .css file to .scss, so in the contextual menu I select `rename` and change the extension name fro `css` to `scss`, after I click elsewhere, the file name become `.scss.css`. Moreover, when I ^click the file again, `rename` dissapears in the contextual menu.

Some aspects of Mac OS are so counter-intuitive and frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via the info panel. Right click the item, select "get info" in the middle of the new window there will be a "Name & Extension" field. Change the extension there.

Answer (score 1):

On finder, press CMD + , and in advanced options you can select something like "Show extensions on file names".